# Can i use connectionString instead of StorageSharedKeyCredentials to Create DataLakeServiceClient?

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am following the Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.datalake-readme?view=azure-dotnet), and they are creating a `DataLakeServiceClient` using `StorageSharedKeyCredentials`. But can we also use the connectionString instead? I only found an example of connectionString being used for python, but no example of connectionString being used with c#

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
            // Create DataLakeServiceClient using StorageSharedKeyCredentials
            DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(serviceUri, sharedKeyCredential);
```

or

```
DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `DataLakeServiceClient` using `connectionString`. The code is same as you second code sample.

```
DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Here is the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakeserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Files_DataLake_DataLakeServiceClient__ctor_System_String_), you can find this.